# Actualizar todas las columnas que tengan el mismo nombre entre dos tablas en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo dos tablas con varios nombres de columna que se parecen y quisiera saber la forma de hacer un `UPDATE` de una tabla a otra sin tener que especificar todos los nombres de columna.

Supongamos que tengo entre las dos tablas 50 nombres de columnas que son idénticos entre ellas:

**tabla1**

`id, col1, col2, col3 ... col50`

**tabla2**

`id, col1, col2, col3 ... col50`

Si quiero actualizar datos de una tabla a otra puedo hacer esto:

```
UPDATE tabla1 a
JOIN tabla2 b ON a.id = b.id
   SET 
   a.col1 = b.col1,
   a.col2 = b.col2
   -- ... ¡si pudiera evitarme tener que escribir esto 50 veces!
   a.colN = b.colN

WHERE b.id=10908576;
```

**¿Es posible hacer el `UPDATE` de todas las columnas que se llamen igual entre las dos tablas sin tener que poner cada vez en el `SET` lo siguiente: `a.colN = b.colN`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No existe ninguna clausula SQL que permita hacer lo que esperas, la única forma es construir de forma dinámica una consulta de actualización tal como te lo mencionó antes Javier. Veamos como sería:

En primer lugar tenemos dos tablas que tienen algunos campos con el mismo nombre (suponemos que son del mismo tipo y la misma longitud)

```
create table tabla1 (
    id int,
    col1 int,
    col2 int,
    col3 int,
    col4 int
);

create table tabla2 (
    id int,
    col1 int,
    col2 int,
    col3 int
);

INSERT INTO tabla1 (id, col1, col2, col3, col4) values (1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
INSERT INTO tabla2 (id, col1, col2, col3) values (1, 1, 1, 1);
```

Y queremos actualizar los datos de `Tabla1` de los campos "compartidos" sin contar el `id` con los mismos valores de la `tabla2`. En nuestro ejemplo serían los campos `col1`, `col2`y `col3` y descartamos el `id` por que obviamente no queremos actualizarlo. Para esto vamos a construir una sentencia de `update` dinámica a partir de la tabla `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`

```
SET @campos = '';

SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT( concat('    a.',C1.COLUMN_NAME, ' = b.', C1.COLUMN_NAME) separator ',\n' )
  INTO @campos
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C1
  INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C2
      ON C2.COLUMN_NAME = C1.COLUMN_NAME
  WHERE C1.TABLE_NAME = 'tabla1'
        AND C2.TABLE_NAME = 'tabla2'
        AND C1.COLUMN_NAME <> 'id';
        AND C1.TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
        AND C2.TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE();

-- Seteamos el id que queremos actualizar  
SET @id  = '1';

SET @sql = CONCAT('UPDATE tabla1 a\nJOIN tabla2 b\n    ON a.id = b.id\nSET\n', @campos, '\nWHERE a.id = ', @id, '');

SELECT @sql;
```

Con esto completamos nuestra variable `@Sql` con la siguiente información:

```
UPDATE tabla1 a
JOIN tabla2 b
    ON a.id = b.id
SET
    a.col1 = b.col1,
    a.col2 = b.col2,
    a.col3 = b.col3
WHERE a.id = 1
```

Ahora queda claro lo que queremos lograr, simplemente quedaría ejecutar esta consulta de la siguiente forma:

```
-- Actualización
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hasta donde yo sé, no hay forma de ahorrarte especificar los nombres de las columnas. Si estás usando un lenguaje interpretado que te permita manipular el SQL antes de lanzarlo, sí podrías construir la lista de columnas interrogando el *esquema* de la base de datos para obtener la lista de columnas.

La consulta siguiente devuelve la lista de columnas de una tabla que empiecen por "col":

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE table_name = 'tabla1'
  AND column_name LIKE 'col%';
```

A partir de esa lista se podría elaborar la consulta. Si estás lanzando la consulta directamente, entonces podrías obtener primero la lista de columnas que quieres y luego llevártelas a tu editor favorito para preparar la consulta. Cualquier editor que permita macros te ahorrará bastante tiempo.

Si empleas un usuario que pueda ver varias bases de datos, en la consulta al *esquema* es posible que tengas que especificar el nombre de la base de datos mediante `AND table_schema = 'nombre_de_la_db'`.

Comment: Gracias. Necesito actualizar varias tablas con muchos nombres de columnas idénticas, pero directamente desde el manejador de BD, ya que es algo puntual, por lo que he descartado escribir código para hacerlo.